# How to Export CSV File to Custom Module Table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2.6

How to add **Magento 2** export functionality to your **module** in Magento 2?

Using this side

> System -> Data Transfer -> Export

Any solution??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I crate a Admin Grid using Ui-Component.

You  want all Data you have create a Custom Export  Button that export your all data.

edit in your Ui-Component file where  Admin Grid Show

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\ui_component**

Add this code to add Button into Admin Grid

***Ui-ComponentFIleName.xml***

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">

    <item name="import" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
    </item>

    <item name="export" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">export</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
    </item>

</item>
```

**Now create a File that Export or Import Data. File Name must be same as you define in Ui-Component file**

```
  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>

  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
```

File path must be like this

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \ Controller \ Adminhtml \ [Controller_name] \ Exportdata.php**

***Exportdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Controller_name];

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Exportdata extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $_locationFactory; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \[vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\locatorFactory $locationFactory // This is returns Collaction of Data

    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
       $this->_locationFactory = $locationFactory;
       $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); // VAR Directory Path
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/export-data-' .$name. '.csv'; // at Directory path Create a Folder Export and FIle
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        //column name dispay in your CSV 

        $columns = ['Col-1-name','Col-2-name','Col-3-name','Col-4-name','Col-5-name','Col-6-name','Col-7-name','Col-8-name','Col-9-name',];

            foreach ($columns as $column) 
            {
                $header[] = $column; //storecolumn in Header array
            }

        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $location = $this->_locationFactory->create();
        $location_collection = $location->getCollection(); // get Collection of Table data 

        foreach($location_collection as $item){

            $itemData = [];

            // column name must same as in your Database Table 

            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-1-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-2-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-3-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-4-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-5-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-6-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-7-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-8-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-9-name');

            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);

        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $csvfilename = 'locator-import-'.$name.'.csv';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    }


}
```

Now you can Click on the Export Button and See your .csv file Downloaded below.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
1,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```