# Magento 2 export orders grid csv programmatically

Tags: magento2, export, order-grid

I have been searching how to export the Orders csv that is found in Orders Grid, I have not found anything regarded to that.

This is the only file I have found about exporting orders to csv.

```
/var/www/html/emall_dev/vendor/magento/module-reports/Test/Unit/Controller/Adminhtml/Report/Customer/ExportOrdersCsvTest.php
```

But it's a test file, I don't know what Test folder means.
I need to create a cronjob to constantly export the order grid programmatically.

Thanks!

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291211/82670

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two options:

1. Use any third-party paid or free extension to export order data
   https://www.mageplaza.com/review/order-export/
2. Create custom module, add export order script/code based require field and set it in the cron.

Please let me know if you need any other help.